# iOS Storyboards - Auto layout constraint issue with iPhone 5 - iPhone 6

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following constraints attached to an input field. However when I switch from iPhone 6 to iPhone to trailing constraint of 16 isn't applied.

Why is this happening. I don't have an width constraint so why would it behave this way - and how do i fix it.

[image]

Comment: Constraints always apply on evry device, pls check preview. Make sure you have given correct constraints, uI behave according to it.

Comment: It is being applied. The orange outline means that the current position doesn’t match where autolayout will put it. Click the circular arrow in the constraints section of the window bottom bar and it should jump into place

Answer (score 0):

These are just warnings, that you can ignore. Yellow marked warning, is a kind of suggestion for update, it won't make any effect/changes in your interface design and their frames until you apply suggestion.

Simple advice: Do not change Interface design (device) size in storyboard. Choose one fixed device size according to your project target (I suggest iPhone 4S or iPhone 5) and setup your all interface design for your project with respect to fixed device size.

Note: Warning will be not visible to you, until you change device (frame size) in your storyboard layout

To check, interface preview for different size of devices (including iPads), there is an option for preview of all size of device. Without changing your storyboard interface view (view controller) size, you can see preview of all layouts from preview screen.

Here is snapshot, that I designed for device iPhone 4S but I can see preview for latest update of iPhone X also, without changing storyboard layout.

[image]